# Am i promise chaining correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

```
onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const user = {
        fname: this.state.firstname,
        lname: this.state.lastname,
        email: this.state.email,
        username: this.state.username,
        password: this.state.password
    }

    new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        this.props.fetchUser(this.state.username)
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({failed: this.props.exists})
                if(!this.state.failed)
                    this.props.registerUser(user)
            })
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({registered: this.props.status});
                resolve();
            })
    })
}
```

This is my attempt at chaining promises. The idea was that registered should update correctly to the state of this.props.status (true/false).

When this.props.registerUser is called in the first promise, it changes this.props.status to true. However, registered is being set to false (which is the value of this.props.status before registerUser is called), rather than true.

I know for sure that this.props.status is changing to true, but the state of registered isn't changing.

I'm new to this stuff.

Comment: Since `fetchUser` seems to return a promise already, it's unnecessary to wrap the whole thing inside a `new Promise`.

Comment: Also, if you are changing state and then reading the value of the new state, make sure to do that in the callback (second parameter) to `setState`. `setState` is not promises to run synchronously.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that `fetchUser` and `registerUser` are functions that return promises. In that case, you do not need to wrap the call for `fetchUser` in a `new Promise(...)` since it will return a promise when invoked.

The reason that the second `then(...)` is not being called, is that you never return a promise from the first `then(...)`.

```
if(!this.state.failed)
    this.props.registerUser(user)
```

should become

```
if(!this.state.failed)
    return this.props.registerUser(user)
```

With these two modifications, your code should look like so

```
this.props.fetchUser(this.state.username)
    .then(res => {
        this.setState({
            failed: this.props.exists
        });
        if (!this.state.failed) {
            return this.props.registerUser(user)
        }
    })
    .then(res => {
        this.setState({
            registered: this.props.status
        });
    })
```

Furthermore, you would expect to read the result of `fetchUser(...)` on the `res` object rather than the component props.

One final caveat that you should be aware of is that setting the state and reading it immediately after, is not guaranteed to always work as expected. The safe way to do it, is to pass a function as your second argument to `setState` and that will be invoked when the state is updated by React.

The simplest way to do it in this case is to avoid reading the state altogether and instead using a temporary variable.

```
const exists = this.props.exists;
this.setState({
    failed: exists
});
if (!exists ) {
    return this.props.registerUser(user)
}
```